# What is the different between save(), create() and update () in django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I m confused when making api on django rest framework using serializers, please tell me exact different between save(), create() and update() methods, my code sample is as follow,

**View.py**

```
class AddUser(views.APIView):
    serializer_class = UserForAdminSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        serializer = UserForAdminSerializer(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():

            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class UserForAdminSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    first_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'name', 'username', 'email', 'password',
                  'total_exp_year', 'total_exp_month', 'voteup_count', 'is_featured',
                  'is_active', 'headline', 'description', 'profile_picture', )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

on the above code in view.py file i m used save() method and serializers.py using save() or update() method so please explain me how it's working and clear my confusion between save() and create()

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Usually the best way to get a good understanding of the code is to actually read it, so let's take a look at the [source](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py):

```
class BaseSerializer(Field):
    ...
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        raise NotImplementedError('`update()` must be implemented.')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        raise NotImplementedError('`create()` must be implemented.')

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        ...
        ... a lot of assertions and safety checks ...
        ... 

        validated_data = dict(
            list(self.validated_data.items()) +
            list(kwargs.items())
        )

        if self.instance is not None:
            self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
            ....
        else:
            self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
            ...
        return self.instance
```

Okay, so, in this base class methods `update` and `create` are left to concrete subclasses to be implemented (as details will vary for serializers such as `ListSerializer` or `ModelSerializer`).

However, `save` *is* implemented and it basically just checks if object is new or existing (`if self.instance is not None`) and calls `update` or `create` respectively. **This** code will be called in every other serializer.

Let's take a look at concrete subclass:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    ...
    ... some stuff happening
    ...

    try:
        # Here is the important part! Creating new object!
        instance = ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)
    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError(msg)

    # Save many-to-many relationships after the instance is created.
    if many_to_many:
        for field_name, value in many_to_many.items():
            set_many(instance, field_name, value)

    return instance


def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    raise_errors_on_nested_writes('update', self, validated_data)
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(instance)

    # Simply set each attribute on the instance, and then save it.
    # Note that unlike `.create()` we don't need to treat many-to-many
    # relationships as being a special case. During updates we already
    # have an instance pk for the relationships to be associated with.
    for attr, value in validated_data.items():
        if attr in info.relations and info.relations[attr].to_many:
            set_many(instance, attr, value)
        else:
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
    instance.save()

    return instance
```

As you can see both `create` and `update` call `set_many(instance, attr, value)` to set values for object attributes. However, `create` does one **critical** call before: `ModelClass.objects.create(**validated_data)`. This actually creates new instance.

I hope this clears it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks Siegmeyer :)

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between self and instance in the update definition?

Comment: @LittleBrain and to anyone wondering in the future, self is actually the current instance of the Serializer, as instance is an instance of the Model referenced by the Serializer. So the update() method of the Serializer implements how the Serializer should manipulate the model instance.

Answer (score 10):

In Django Rest Framework [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly) they explained very clearly when to override save method and when create method.

I am posting their explanation here for your convenience

---

In some cases the .create() and .update() method names may not be meaningful. For example, in a contact form we may not be creating new instances, but instead sending an email or other message.
In these cases you might instead choose to override .save() directly, as being more readable and meaningful.

Example:-

```
class ContactForm(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    message = serializers.CharField()

    def save(self):
        email = self.validated_data['email']
        message = self.validated_data['message']
        send_email(from=email, message=message)
```

Comment: Plz look a glance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119536/how-to-get-data-from-another-tablemodel-in-rest-api-html-form-using-django-res  also